# Reducing degrees of freedom of a system described by an equation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, coordinate-systems, constrained-dynamics

Let's consider a system described by this simple equation:

$x^{2}+y^{2}=5$

this represents a holonomic constraint. Suppose I would like to reduce the degrees of freedom of this system, I should be able to do it since is described by a holonomic constraint. However, both $x^{2}$ and $y^{2}$ are not invertible. So how can I write one of them as a function of the other?

Comment: Can you think of a better coordinate system than rectangular coordinates?

Comment: Yes, i've understood. However what i don't understand is which are the advantages of expressing a system as an equation $f(q_{1},...,q_{n})=0$. Can you explain to me ?

Comment: In practice, the physical system under consideration may imply the holonomic constraint $f(q,t)\approx 0$ directly rather than some other version.

Comment: Why, intuitively, in cartesian coordinates isn't immediate to see that there is only 1 degree of freedom, whereas in polar coordinates you immediately see it ?

Comment: Another thing i have not understood. Why if my system is described by $f(q_{1},...,q_{n})=0$ i can ALWAYS represent one variable as a function of the other ?